# Views: Combine Fields Filter "OR"?

Tags: 7, views

How do I combine two fields using the Views Global: Combine Fields Filter using an "Or" statement? For example, if my  filter combines Field A and Field B and my content is has Field A->Option A, Field B-> option C, it would show up when my filter is set to A OR C.

Desired results:

Field A
 - **Option A**
 - Option B
 - Option C

Field B
 - Option A
 - Option B
 - **Option C**

Combined Filter select Menu: **Option A**
 Expected result, content shows.

The default behavior seems to require that value is present in both field not either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was accomplished using Operator "CONTAINS" vs default "IS EQUAL TO"

I set a custom group and inputted values manually and had the operator set to contains, so for example if I select "Option A" in my filter and piece of content with either field a or field b with "option a" selected would show up.